# Speech bubbles in a chatbot application using html css javascript & Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chatbot

First simple and basic coding project to build a chat bot. Its built and functional but now I want the messages sent from the bot and user to appear in speech bubbles inside the chat log ..[chat bot showing messages appearing in chatlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSduM.png) but I'm absolutely lost on this next stage! Would I have to build the speech bubbles in html and css first, hide them and then show them when a new message is sent?

Super lost, so any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Whenever a new message is received by the bot, or typed by the user, use jQuery's [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) function to add the appropriate HTML for that particular speech bubble. Bot bubbles could be styled with CSS to float left and user bubbles would float right (or vice-versa). Here's an [example bot](https://botmakr.net/chat/BotMakr) that does it that way.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Managed to get separate bubbles and populate them with user and bot messages. Just haven’t managed to get a separate bubble to create for each new message. At the moment the same bubble is filling with new messages. But I’ll keep trying. Thanks for the help :)